# Is there something opposite to Semaphore

Tags: windows, synchronization, ipc

Is there something opposite to [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685129%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)? I am looking for something system-wide process-independant that I could use to *count* how much threads are using a resource, and not so much *limit* how much threads are using a resource.
Or should I consider using a semaphore with a pretty high maximum count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semaphores can be released or acquired in any order. I would recommend that you simply release the semaphore when your thread starts using the resource and acquire it when done with the resource.

This is assuming you need cross-process communication. If you don;t, by all means use a counter variable.

May I ask why you're doing this?

Comment: In the http://xxm.sf.net project, the IIS handler loading an xxm library, can't unload a library fully to auto-update it when more than one w3wp.exe has the xxl loaded/locked. So I need some sort of IPC in order not to require a limit of 1 worker process.

Comment: In that case, a semaphore as I described would work. In the updater, try to acquire the semaphore. If you cannot without blocking, the file can be updated. Note you may want a mutex to protect against the library being loaded during update as well.

Comment: What I really want is that new calls to the library 'stall' on some kind of sync call. If you put it this way, I can't use WaitForSingleObject on that semaphore. You're right about the mutex, but I might need one or two events also.